# Count with grouping in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to count a number of rows for each value appearing in a column. Is there an easy way to do this in excel?

Let's say I have the following table:

```
A    B     C
1   Cat    A
3   Cat    A
3   Cat    B
4   Dog    A
5   Cat    B
```

I want to get the following result:

```
B    Row_Count
Cat   4
Dog   1
```

Also, it would be nice to be able to SUM

```
B    SUM_Col_A
Cat   12
Dog   4
```

But I cannot specify strings "Cat" and "Dog" explicitly because my columns contain >1000 distinct values.

Comment: You can use the Consolidate option (Data->Data Tools->Consolidate). First select the A&B columns and use Consolidate with COUNT and then with SUM.

Comment: @User194076,, check I've posted a solution, if you can handle VBA code then for the faster process I can suggest you bunch of codes since you have written that you have more that 1000 Rows.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Many ways.. simplest one (to my view) is to use a pivot table but it depends on your needs..

[image]

If you define your data table with a name then it will expand automatically as you add value and a refresh on the pivot will update the numbers

Comment: It would be more useful if you provide the step how to create a "pivot table"

Comment: Something about pivot table: https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html

Answer (score 4):

**To find the Grand Total of Cat & Dog use the following Formula.**

`=SUMIF($B$2:$B$6,$B$8,$A$2:$A$6)`

`=SUMIF($B$2:$B$6,$B$9,$A$2:$A$6)`

**To find the Total of Cat & Dog use these Formula.**

`=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$6,$B$11)`

`=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$6,$B$12)`

Check the screen shot.

[image]

*I do hope this help you.*

Comment: @User194076,, check this solution and if you can handle the VBA code then I can suggest you bunch of codes for the faster process, since you have written that you have more that 1000 Rows.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I don't think this will work since Cat and Dog are hardcoded in formula.

Comment: @user194076,, now check,, I've made the Formula dynamic,, simply replaced the criteria with their respective cell address  :-)  .

Answer (score -4):

Step-1:You can copy B column to a new sheet and apply remove duplicates
Step-2: use countif and sumif formula on them